# Problema con las etiquetas en un gráfico geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo una función del siguiente estilo

```
    function(){
      for(){
          #crea data frame del estilo: 
          data.frame(test=c(),pvalor=c())
          }
      #Crea un grid para las gráficas resultantes de cada una de las iteraciones del for()    
      ggplot(aes(x=test,y=pvalor,label=pvalor))+
            geom_point()+
            geom_text(aes(label=pvalor))+
            facet_grid()
    }
```

Sin embargo, al mostrar el gráfico no me aparecen las etiquetas de texto que inserté con `geom_text`, como se ve en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer cada gráfico por separado, las etiquetas, me funciona correctamente . No sé si es por `facet_grid()` que no se muestran correctamente en el gráfico conjunto.

Un ejemplo de los datos:

```
df<-data.frame(test=rep(c("CR0","CR1","CR2"),9),ng=c(rep(25,9),rep(50,9),rep(100,9)),coef=rep(c(rep(0.1,3),rep(0.5,3),rep(0.8,3)),3),pvalor=runif(27,min = 0.05,max = 0.1))
```

Comment: Trata de compartir un ejemplo de los datos, es muy difícil reproducir tu ejemplo para poder ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: He añadido un ejemplo de los datos para que reproducir un ejemplo. Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que puedes resolverlo, de la siguiente forma:

```
set.seed(1)
df<-data.frame(test=rep(c("CR0","CR1","CR2"),9),
               ng=c(rep(25,9),rep(50,9),rep(100,9)),
               coef=rep(c(rep(0.1,3),rep(0.5,3),rep(0.8,3)),3),
               pvalor=runif(27,min = 0.05,max = 0.1))

ggplot(df, aes(x=test, y=pvalor)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%.4f", pvalor), y = pvalor - .003), cex=3, col="blue") +
    facet_grid(coef ~ ng)
```

Para las etiquetas usamos `geom_text()` con un formateo de `pvalor` a 4 decimales, la etiqueta la ubicaremos ligeramente abajo del punto ajustando del valor `y`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En efecto solucionó el problema. Puede ser que el inconveniente estuviera la extensión de los decimales que estoy usando (hasta 10 posiciones). Pero es solo una suposición. Muchas gracias!